# How Can I Remove flutter_webview_plugin from my Flutter Project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing an app for Android and iOS but I can't debug with Android emulator because there is an error.

When emulator debug starts or do `flutter pub get`, an error is displayed like below.

```
The plugin `flutter_webview_plugin` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future      
release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
```

To remove this error, I removed `flutter_webview_plugin` from `pubspec.yaml` and execute `flutter pub get`.
But this error still displayed.

## doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at C:\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (9 days ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\yukik.000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.11)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.11.32228.343
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] VS Code (version 1.68.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\yukik.000\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)       • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739]
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.67
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 102.0.1245.41

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe it's cached in your local folders. I've witnessed that number of times in my cases. Try running `flutter clean` first and then run `flutter pub get` for a starter.

Answer (score 0):

If flutter clean && flutter pub get not working, maybe one of your dependencies use webview (flutter_html, video player, etc). You maybe need to check if your Flutter app is update to date : https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration (take only few minutes)